JAVA with IDE DrJAVA - Static error This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]
I am learning JAVA and for one of my exercice I am using DrJAVA IDE and I can't find issue to the following code whose error on console is "This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]."
abstract class Forme {
    protected String couleur;
    protected int x, y;

    public Forme(String couleur, int x, int y) {
        this.couleur = couleur;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public abstract String toString();
}

class Cercle extends Forme {
    private int rayon;

    public Cercle(String couleur, int x, int y, int rayon) {
        super(couleur, x, y);
        this.rayon = rayon;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "<circle cx=\"" + x + "\" cy=\"" + y + "\" r=\"" + rayon + "\" fill=\"" + couleur + "\" />";
    }
}

class Rectangle extends Forme {
    private int width, height;

    public Rectangle(String couleur, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        super(couleur, x, y);
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "<rect x=\"" + x + "\" y=\"" + y + "\" width=\"" + width + "\" height=\"" + height + "\" fill=\"" + couleur +
               "\" />";
    }
}

class TestFormes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cercle cercle = new Cercle("red", 50, 50, 20);
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle("blue", 10, 10, 100, 50);

        System.out.println(cercle);
        System.out.println(rectangle);
    }
}

No problem regarding compilation but running is failed. I have tried to work on the main method but nothing WORKS,

Welcome to [so]. Please take the [tour] (earn a badge!) and read the [ask] page for tips on how to improve this question.  Good questions have a better chance at getting answers from the community

I do not know DrJava, it seems like it is trying to run a class with main(), that is, not TestFormes - try selecting that class before running or move the class code to the start of the file.. (or read help of DrJava)

Any more output in the console that could help us identify the problem? The code itself looks good - it must be something in your IDE - maybe you are launching wrong class

Take all that code you just posted, rename the (single, whole) file TestFormes.java, change class TestFormes to public class TestFormes and compile and run. In time you might separate all the other class sources into their own file, removing them from TestFormes.java as you do so

@g00se This could as well be the answer to OP, adding of course the explanation as why it requires the file name and main class to match :)
